# Storing Directory Hierarchy in a Key-Value Data store

Tags: mongodb, key-value

What is a clean/efficient method for storing the directory Hierarchy/tree in a Key-Value database (in my case MongoDB but any of them)?

For example a tree structure

```
- Cars 
   + Audi 
   + BMW
      - M5
   + Ford
- Color
   + Red
      - Apple
      - Cherry
   + Purple
- Funny
```

The method I am using now, each object links to it's parent

```
{ 
  dir: "red"
  parent-dir: "color"
}
```

This makes it very efficient/fast to insert and reorder any aspect of the tree (for example if I want to move Red and all it's children to the Cars directory).

But this method sucks when I want to all subdirectories and their children for a given directory recursively. To make it efficient to parse I can have a structure for example

```
{ 
  dir: "red"
  children: "audi, bmw, ford"
}

{ 
  dir: "bmw"
  children: "m5"
}
```

But if I want to modify the tree, a whole bunch of objects need to touched and modified.

Are there any other methods to storing a directory structure in a KV store?

Comment: Really this question is more general... What is the best way to store ANY hierarchical data in a KV data store...

Comment: +1: I did not know about this KV-trend. I learned something new, thanks.

Comment: PS: for those like me, here is a decent exposition of KV: http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2009/02/is-the-relational-database-doomed.php

Comment: MonogoDB is **NOT** a key value store! [It's a document oriented database database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The method you currently use now is called [adjacency list model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list_model).

Another model to store hierarchical data in a (relational) database is the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). Its [implementation in SQL databases is well known](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Also see [this article for the modified preorder tree traversal algorithm](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database).

A very simple method: you could store a path per object - with those it should be easy to query trees in NOSQL databases:

```
{ path: "Color", ... }
{ path: "Color.Red", ... }
{ path: "Color.Red.Apple", ... }
{ path: "Color.Red.Cherry", ... }
```

When nodes will be removed or renamed some paths must be updated. But in general, this method looks promising. You just have to reserve a special character as separator. The storage space overhead should be negligible.

*edit: this method is called [materialized path](https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-9902)*

Finally, here is [a comparison of different methods for hierarchical data in NOSQL databases](http://seancribbs.com/tech/2009/09/28/modeling-a-tree-in-a-document-database).

Comment: There is a pretty good article in the MongoDB Documentation about the possibilities to store trees: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB

Comment: @Frunsi Why not use Zookeeper to store this information instead as it comes with in built support for hierarchy

Comment: @Itachi: Why? Why not? This is as off-topic as if I'd ask you why don't you always use a child safety seat when driving in a car.

Comment: Working link for Tree Structures: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a huge amount of NOSQL experience, so this isn't a definitive answer, but here's how I'd approach it:

I would likely use your first approach, where you have:

```
{
  dir: 'dir_name',
  parent_dir: 'parent_dir_name'
}
```

And then set up a map-reduce to quickly query the children of a directory. MongoDB's map-reduce functionality is still only available in the development branch and I haven't worked with it yet, but in CouchDB (and I assume, with a few modification, in MongoDB) you could do something like:

```
map:
function(doc) {
  emit( doc.parent_dir, doc.dir );
}

reduce:
function(key, values) {
  return( values );
}
```

Which would give you the list of sub-directories for each parent directory.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest storing a heap to the the id's of the data items.
I think this is the best plan.  If you need lots and lots of stuff any heap element could be an index to another heap.

eg

`{ "id:xxx", "id:yyy", "sub-heap-id:zzz"....}`

If this is not clear post a comment and I will explain more when I get home.

Answer (score -3):

Make an index!

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes