# How to store data in a MongoDB collection as a heap?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm, mean-stack

I'm using the MEAN stack for my web application which contains data that can be most efficiently stored and accessed as a heap structure. My application will have many calls (about a few hundred per minute) to retrieve the minimum element in a collection and work with it independently each time.  Since I would like to use Node.js and MongoDB (hence the MEAN stack), I'm wondering how to build the data as a heap.

**Ideally I would like to incorporate [npm's heap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/heap) somehow into the MEAN stack's MongoDB and/or Mongoose.  But I'm not sure where and how.**

Yes I could use MongDB's sort(), but that would mean I have to sort the collection every single time, based on what this [answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360583/4825465)

```
db.the_collection.find().sort({the_field: 1}).limit(1)
```

Sorting basically the same thing hundreds of times per minute would be bad, wouldn't it? Or is MongoDB so very efficient that it can handle this?

Someone also mentioned $min. I don't know if it'll help as I don't even know [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32940972/4825465) compared to `sort()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, MongoDB is a document-centric repository storing JSON documents (really BSON but let's keep it simple for now). And, a [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is a form of specialized tree. My assumption is you will model your heap(s) as a JSON document and have to code the insertion and retrieval methods in JavaScript. I am going to play around with this some more, but perhaps the research will help you to get farther.

So, here are two great pieces of research to help you:

1. Modeling a tree in a document database [here](http://seancribbs.com/tech/2009/09/28/modeling-a-tree-in-a-document-database/).
2. Storing a directory hierarchy in a Key Value store [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619058/storing-directory-hierarchy-in-a-key-value-data-store). (Yes, I know MongoDB is technically not a KV store, but there is good information in the post...)

Comment: Ok, this may be interesting as well...https://github.com/thauburger/js-heap/blob/master/package.json

Comment: How's https://github.com/thauburger/js-heap better than https://www.npmjs.com/package/heap?

Comment: I can't say that it is. Only commenting on additional research/findings. I plan on trying both to see which one may be better ...

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research, I have decided to just put a complex index in my Mongoose schema and then use MongoDB's find() and sort(). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32961123/4825465) for more details.