# In a MEAN stack, how can I do one-time MongoDB indexing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am using Node.js and MongoDB with Mongoose. 
I am connecting to Mongoose form Node.js as,

```
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database_name')
```

How can configure once in node.js to [create index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/) on collection ?

The directory structure of my App is, based on [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial):

```
HTML        views/
Angular.js  public/javascript/
Express.js  routes/
Node.js     app.js
Mongoose js models/, set up in app.js
Mongo db    set up in app.js
```

Guide me on how to give index on a MongoDB collection form Node.js.

Comment: Using mongoose you will generally want to [define the indexes with the schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes).

Comment: Hi Carl Groner, thanks. Can you also check what I wrote in the answer below about putting the compound index line in the app.js file is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As people have commented, the best way is to set up the index in the Mongoose schema. In my case it's in the models/Animal.js file.

For single indexing, you can define when you define the schema

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true }
});
```

See [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) for more info.

For [compound indexing](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/indexes.html), you can then add a line in the same file after the Schema definition like this:

```
animalSchema.index({"tags": 1, "name": 1});
```

[Sort order](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/#sort-order) is either ascending (1) or descending (-1).

Btw, you can use `db.animal.find().sort({tags: 1, name: 1}).limit(1)` to get the first one.