# Build File Tree of Cloud Storage in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, subdirectory

I want to show my users a folder structure, where images are placed in (they then can choose and download/view them).

The Images are in the right "folders" of Storage. But as far as I know, it's not possible to retrieve a folder-structure from Storage.

How can I build a Folder-Structure in Cloud Firestore for this? Is this even the right approach? Or is there a way simpler (out-of-the-box) solution for this problem?

I already have a Cloud function for resizing the images and creating a Document with the Path for every image that gets triggered when a new image is uploaded. 
Would it be a good to just check for every image, if the folder already exists or if a new one was created and if thats the case creates a new document with the path. Later i could then get all images with folder1/{filename}**.jpg** and all nested folders of folder1 (get all folders where folder1 is the penultimate?).

Might be completly bullshit I wrote here, because I have no idea how such systems are usualy built, so I am really happy for every advice you can give me :).

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Storing Directory Hierarchy in a Key-Value Data store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619058/storing-directory-hierarchy-in-a-key-value-data-store), which shows how to model a directory in a key-value database.

Comment: Thank you Frank! I went with the version of saving the parent-path. That works pretty well.

Comment: Good to hear Karl!